# lerna | right way to install external package on multiple projects

Tags: javascript, typescript, lerna

We are using Lerna to manage our mono-repo projects, and I wish to know the best way to install an external package in my projects and ensure that all of them are using the same version.

My project structure (my-Main-A and my my-Main-B both use my-common):

- my-Main-A

  - my-common
- my-Main-B

  - my-common

Should I install my external package at the common project and export it from there?

```
import joi from "joi";

export {joi};
```

and then import it into the other project:

```
import {joi} from my-common;
```

Or should I install it on all of the 3 projects?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar case and I went with adding the library to all of my packages and used `--exact` to get the package exact same version

If you want to add a library to a package then exported from there, your shared package should be dependent on all other packages and you have to link it with other packages

```
# add package "a" to multiple packages
lerna add a --scope=b --scope=c --scope=d  --exact
```